# What's a real life example of a case in which the conditional expectation and unconditional expectation differ?

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

My questions are

- We have one variable, is called, "a" and mean of "a" is 5664.

is this  unconditional mean ?

[image]

- When we regress b on a (dependent is a, independent is b)

Mean Dependent Var is 5664

[image]

**And when conditional mean is different from unconditional mean** ? Can you explain with concrete sample ?

Comment: *Any* regression model gives such an example.

Comment: when conditional mean is different from unconditional mean ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the population of human heights. The unconditional mean is some number. The mean of height of adults, so conditioned on the subject being an adult, is taller.

Answer (score 1):

The first way in which these things always differ is that the conditional mean is a *function* of the conditioning value, whereas the unconditional mean is single *value*.  If you take any two random variables $L$ and $R$ then the conditional mean is a function of the form $\mu_{L|R}(r) \equiv \mathbb{E}(L|R=r)$ whereas the unconditional mean is a single value $\mu_L \equiv \mathbb{E}(L)$.  These are related by the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation):

$$\mu_L = \int \limits_\mathscr{R} \mu_{L|R}(r) p_R(r) dr.$$

If you would like an example where the value of the conditional mean is very different from the value of the unconditional mean, just take any two strongly correlated variables $L$ and $R$, and then condition on a value in the extremes of their range.

For example, suppose we take a random person in the world, and let $L$ and $R$ be the respective lengths of that person's left leg and right leg.  Now, consider the difference between the unconditional mean of $L$ (i.e., the mean length of a left leg) versus the conditional mean of $L$ if $R$ is small (i.e., the unconditional mean length of the left leg for a person with a short right leg).

Answer (score 0):

Conditional expectation is a *function*, and expectation is a constant. So the answer is easy: whenever that function is not a constant function.

More details: Let $X,Y$ be random variables and we are interested in the conditional expectation of $Y$ given that $X=x$, where $x$ is a variable ranging over the range of $X$. Write
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
   f(x) = \E \left[ Y \mid X=x\right]
$$
The only way we can have $f(x) = \E Y$ is when $f(x)$ is a constant function, for instance, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.